# PayPal Confirm Payment Made From iOs

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I am using the following code

```
    $header = array(
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken );

    $url = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/' . $data['PaymentId'];

    //cURL starts
    $crl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET,true);
    $reply = curl_exec($crl);

   //error handling for cURL
    if ($reply === false) {
       print_r('Curl error: ' . curl_error($crl));
    }
    curl_close($crl);
    //cURL ends

    //decoding the json data
    $decoded_data = json_decode($reply, true);
```

The response is null although the header etc. look ok. I need to curl to PayPal to check that a payment made on an app has been successful.

Answer (score 0):

The $header should be like this:

`$header = array('Accept:application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken);`

Note that here is not using `=>`, just add the header items directly